# Configuration webpack/typescript: ERROR in Entry module - Can't resolve './src'

Tags: typescript, webpack

I want to configure a blank project with webpack and typesript.

So far this is not going well^^. My entry file (`index.ts`) is not recognized.

```
const path = require('path');

module.export = {
    entry: '../src/index.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    }
};
```

This is how the project structure looks like:

[image]

Maybe some of you guys can help me out on the configuration. I actually followed the steps from the webpack doc. BTW: If i change index.ts to index.js the bundling works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to verify if your webpack setup for typescript works fine.

Below steps are mentioned in [webpack docs for typescript](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) , but not with this much precision, so i would recommend you to follow my below steps to have some progress with debugging your issue

> Install below dev dependencies

```
npm install webpack webpack-cli --save-dev
npm install typescript ts-loader --save-dev
```

> Create a sample script to test if ts gets converted into js

```
./src/index.ts

console.log("in index.ts");
function addNumbers(a: number, b: number) { 
    return a + b; 
} 
var sum: number = addNumbers(10,15) 
console.log('Sum of the two numbers is: ' +sum);
```

> Create tsconfig.json to compile typescript to es5

```
./tsconfig.json

{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

> Create webpack.config.js

```
./webpack.config.js

const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

> Add below entires to your package.json

```
./package.json

"scripts": {
    "webpack" : "webpack",
    "dev" : "npm run webpack -- --mode development",
    "prod" : "npm run webpack -- --mode production"
}
```

> Once above steps are done

- Run webpack, in dev or prod mode `npm run dev or npm run prod`
- You have to see below output, go into `dist` folder to see the generated js bundle

[image]

- Go into `dist` folder and link the generated js bundle to a sample html file say `index.html` for example
- If you run the html file in the browser you would see the js output in browser console

> if you get the results as mentioned above then what does it mean?

This means ts to js converstion happens without any issue

You can find above steps in a project in [my gitrepo](https://github.com/Divine1/so-webpackissue.git).

i've tested this setup and it works without a problem in my machine 
`node 8.11.4 npm 5.6.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your line 3, it has to be `module.exports` instead of `module.export`.